# What is the common/standard practice for Python logging with multiple modules?

Tags: python, logging, coding-style, standards, python-2.6

Let's say I have a script which relies on two modules:

- Main.py
- Module1.py
- Module2.py

Only Main.py will be executed, but in the execution of Main, there are several calls to methods within Module1.py and Module2.py.

Is it more common to...

**1) Log everything into a log for Main.py?**

or

**2) Log everything into a log for each action's respective module?**

(tl;dr if you understand my question, then there's no need to read on.  Otherwise, here's an example):

---

**Examples (using very abbreviated code):**

**Case #1** has only one single log file, let's call it Main.log.  Assume that the logger name is not hardcoded (it is in this example though), so that should I make AnotherMain.py for example, all of the log entries will go into AnotherMain.log

*Main.py:*

```
some_value = Module1.get_value("abc")
some_other_value = Module2.get_value("def")
some_result = some_value + some_other_value
log("main", "some_result evaluated successfully")
```

*Module1.py:*

```
def get_value(key):
   ...
   log("main", "returning value for key from Module1")
```

*Module2.py:*

```
def get_value(key):
   ...
   log("main", "returning value for key from Module2")
```

This would result in Main.log reading:

```
some_result evaluated successfully
returning value for key from Module1
returning value for key from Module2
```

**Case #2** has three log files, one for each module: Main.log, Module1.log, Module2.log.

*Main.py:*

```
some_value = Module1.get_value("abc")
some_other_value = Module2.get_value("def")
some_result = some_value + some_other_value
log("main", "some_result evaluated successfully")
```

*Module1.py:*

```
def get_value(key):
   ...
   log("Module1", "returning value for key")
```

*Module2.py:*

```
def get_value(key):
   ...
   log("Module2", "returning value for key")
```

This would result in three logs, each with one line saying only what happened within that module.

I'm not asking, "which do you prefer," but rather, which is more standard and common?  Which will leave my successors happier to handle and maintain once I'm gone?

Comment: Are you using the `logging` module yet?

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm already using logging.  Question is do I have three loggers (one for each module) or one logger (for the main script and use it in Module1.py and Module2.py)

Comment: That depends **entirely** on your needs. Most programs will use one logfile for `logging` output, but if you feel you need more detail from one specific module, and adjusting the formatter and log level for that module is not enough or drowns out messages for the other modules, then by all means give it a separate file.

Comment: My point is that that kind of decision is a configuration issue, not a programming issue. The `logging` library gives you plenty of flexibility to adjust the configuration, including how many log files you end up with.

Comment: But, from your question, it is not clear at all that you are using the `logging` library; you don't use any of that library's conventions. You talk about separate log files, not logging *objects*. Your `log()` calls use module names. Etc.

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html) page

Comment: I guess my question is poorly worded.  The fact that I'm using python or the logging module is inconsequential to what I wanted to ask: if you have a main program that relies on two components, do the operations of those two components get their own logs, or should everything be put into one log file for the main, including the operations of the two components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is to use the [`logging` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), and leave everything to that library.

Each module uses its own logger:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# ...
log.warn('Do not fnord the frazzle, faf the frobnir instead')
```

and configure logging in the main module; you can configure one log file, or direct output from specific modules to specific files if so desired.

By default loggers propagate everything on to the root logger, but using separate loggers per module gives you flexibility in the future when you want to set up more complex logging configurations.

You can adjust formatting and direct logging to other backends as needed. The formatter has a [lot of options](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) to adjust the generated message, make sure to include the logger name. The [configuration options for formatting, filtering and handling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html) are almost endless.

The point is that how many log files you have and what goes into those files is a matter of *configuration*. Adjust the configuration as your needs change. Start off with something simple; log everything to one file, and progress from there. By giving each module their own logging object, you can configure each logger separately, *or* stick to the default and leave everything to propagate to the root handler.

Comment: Maybe add an example that shows how he can control both his scenario's from handlers in main.py

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I get that, I should have mentioned I'm already using logging.  The question is, do I use getLogger("calling main script"), or do I use getLogger(__ name __) (resulting in three loggers).

Comment: @CptSupermrkt: You use three loggers; the root logger handles formatting, filtering and handling into one log file.